# Perl Debugger: Filehandle as Input

Tags: perl, debugging

I have this problem:
I need to control the perl-debugger from an external script. 
By research I found out about various solutions, but I don't understand them.
I failed to properly set up the RemotePort option (editing ".perldb"), which was the first I tried, and found no useful information on providing a filehandle from which the debugger would get its input (by somehow setting @cmdfhs) 
I found both options over here: http://search.cpan.org/~nwclark/perl-5.8.6/lib/perl5db.pl

It would be nice if you could tell me how to provide the filehandle from which the debugger gets its input, or if you know a link where this is explained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example setting it up using `RemotePort`, which seemed easier to me:

The trick to using `RemotePort` is that you have to have someone listening on the remote end BEFORE you launch the script to be debugged.

As soon as you launch your script with `-d` Perl will attempt to connect to `RemotePort`. So you have to make sure the initial connection succeeds by having someone listening there beforehand.

Here I assume some Linux/Unix variant, which has the `netcat` utility installed. We use `netcat` to wait for incoming connections in this example, but you can use anything else you wish too which is able to create a service port and shuffle data between that and the current TTY:

**In terminal 1**:

```
 # Use netcat to listen for incoming connections on port 9999
 > nc -l -p 9999
```

**In terminal 2**:

```
 # Start perl with -d and request a RemotePort connection 
 > PERLDB_OPTS=RemotePort=127.0.0.1:9999 perl -d my_script.pl
```

As soon as you do that in terminal 1 you will see something like this:

```
Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.39_10
Editor support available.

Enter h or 'h h' for help, or 'man perldebug' for more help.

main::(my_script.pl:4):
  DB<1>
```

There you go..debug away.

Answer (score 0):

[Devel::Trepan](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Trepan) is a gdb-like debugger. Although it has remote control, you can also run it at the outset with the option `--command` which will "source" (in the gdb-sense) or run a series of debugger commands.

To go into remote control, either start the debugger using the `--server` option or inside the debugger use the "[server](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Trepan::CmdProcessor::Command::Server)" command once inside the debugger.

See [Options](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Trepan::Options) for a list of options you can give at the outset.